# Is it possible to send emails from any type of email using common smtp host?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i used Simple Mail Transfer Protocol gmail host to send emails from gmail it works fine.but when try to send email from yahoo or outlook it doesn't work. Is it Possible to send emails from all type of mails like yahoo,outlook etc  in Simple Mail Transfer Protocol using common Simple Mail Transfer Protocol host in c# ?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Yes, C# has built in support for sending emails using any standard SMTP server

If your question is more about why gmail and outlook didn't work when you tried you'll need to include more detail such as error messages. As long as gmail/outlook do provide an accessible and protocol compliant SMTP service on your country/to your location, and you're using it in accordance with their instructions/you're properly authenticating with an account that has access, and they aren't classifying your mail as spam then the mail should be sent as with any other SMTP service

https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040